# GCD / Blocks without ARC Leak

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I have a leak in the following code which uses GCD. Note: I am not using ARC. The leak is exactly at

```
__block NSMutableArray *newImages = [NSMutableArray new];

dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{

    for (NSDictionary *imageData in results) {

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[imageData objectForKey:@"url"]];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *imageData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        if (error == nil && imageData != nil && response.statusCode == 200) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            [newImages addObject:image];
        }

        else {
            self.errorLabel.text = @"An error has occured downloading some images.";
            [self.spinner stopAnimating];
        }
    }
});
```

According to instruments, I am leaking at: `[newImages addObject:image];`. Why is this leaking? `newImages` is an autoreleased object as shown above.

Comment: What version of XCode/Instruments are you using ?

Comment: by the way, there is no reason to use `__block` on `newImages` here at all. `__block` is only useful to be able to assign to the variable inside the block, or to be able to see later assignments to the variable on the outside from inside the block. `newImages` is never assigned to except when it is initialized, before the block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`newImages` is not autoreleased. [`new`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-new) returns an owning reference -- it's equivalent to `[[SomeClass alloc] init]`.

Comment: So, why Instruments flags [newImages addObject:image]; line as the leak ?

Comment: Leaks are not "caused" by a line of code, they're caused by the combined effects of all the code that operates on that object (and, in particular, they're caused by the *absence* of a line releasing the resource, which is obviously impossible to flag the location of). Instruments will tell you what was leaked, where it was allocated, and where it was retained and released, but you need to learn how to interpret its information.